# Changing format of dates in the entire column for multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataset, say:

```
DateJoined      Name       Number      DateLeft

11/03/2015      Tom        001199      11/03/2019
11/03/2016      Bil        001197      12/03/2019
11/03/2017      Mat        001196      13/03/2019
11/03/2018      Jon        001195      14/03/2019
```

I want to only select the columns that have a date and change the format of all the dates within that column to Month/Date/Year.

I've already tried playing around with the code like this, but it comes up with errors.

```
date_cols=[col for col in dataset.columns if 'date' in col]
for col in dataset[date_cols]:
  for row in dataset[date_cols]:
   dataset[date_cols]=pd.to_datetime(dataset[date_cols]).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
   next(row)
next(col)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm still new to pandas and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need for loop here -- using `filter`

```
s=df.filter(like='Date').apply(pd.to_datetime,dayfirst=True)
df[s.columns]=s
df
  DateJoined Name  Number   DateLeft
0 2015-03-11  Tom    1199 2019-03-11
1 2016-03-11  Bil    1197 2019-03-12
2 2017-03-11  Mat    1196 2019-03-13
3 2018-03-11  Jon    1195 2019-03-14
```